# How to implement Sheets in SwiftUI while using Generics and MVVM?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, generics, swiftui

**Context**

I am currently working on a system for handling `Sheets` in SwiftUI. However, I encountered a problem when utilizing the MVVM Design Pattern and generics.

I have a `Sheet` struct containing the generic `View` the `Sheet` should display. I also have an `@Published` variable in the view model holding the currently active `Sheet`.

However, obviously, this does not allow sheets with different view types, since I get the following compiler errors:

> **Error 1:** Reference to generic type 'Sheet' requires arguments in <...>

> **Error 2:** 'nil' requires a contextual type

---

**Code**

```swift
public struct Sheet<Content: View>: Identifiable {
    public let id = UUID()
    
    let content: Content
    
    public init(@ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self.content = content()
    }
}

public class SheetViewModel: ObservableObject {
    public static let shared = SheetViewModel()
    
    private init() {}
    
    @Published var sheet: Sheet?                                   // Error 1
    
    public func present<Content: View>(_ sheet: Sheet<Content>) {
        self.sheet = sheet
    }
    
    public func present<Content: View>(@ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self.sheet = CRSheet(content: content)
    }
    
    public func dismiss() {
        self.sheet = nil                                          // Error 2
    }
}

public struct SheetViewModifier: ViewModifier {
    @ObservedObject private var sheetVM = SheetViewModel.shared
    
    public func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .sheet(item: $sheetVM.sheet) { sheet in
                sheet.content
            }
    }
}
```

---

**Question**

- How can I resolve the errors, especially, be able to store sheets with different generic views inside the same `@Published` Variable and later use them inside the view modifier?

My idea was to maybe store the `View` as `any View` inside the sheet Struct`. However, I am not sure, how to use it inside the view modifier then?

***Please Note:** This code is part of a package and therefore needs to be accessed from outside. The generic content therefore must be passed to the `present(_)` Method.*

Comment: You are trying to override the way SwiftUI works, this will be an uphill battle

Comment: @loremipsum thanks for your answer, but what do you mean by that? Without using a `Generic Content`, this would be standard `SwiftUI` code.

Comment: SwiftUI is all about identity, when you put a SwiftUI view in a model that conforms to identifiable you are overriding SwiftUI’s mechanism for determining identity and reloading views as appropriate. Watch Demystify SwiftUI you might get some insight.

Comment: Also, views should also never be tied to a view model. In theory you should be able to use the same view model for SwiftUI and UIKit with only the view/uiview/uiviewcontroller being different. At least that is how it would work in a property decoupled app.

Comment: And please notice that `grey background text` is meant to be used for code within normal text, when you overdo it by using it for all possible words it only makes the text harder to read.

Comment: @loremipsum that makes sense and thanks for the recommendation. Previously, I had an Enum of supported Sheets and switched through it inside the ViewModifiers `.sheet(item, content)` Modifier. However, this does not work for a Package where you can't change either the Enum or the Modifier.
What would be best approach then for achieving my goal in a SwiftUI way?

Comment: There isn’t enough information. In SwiftUI your View should adapt to the model. Have models for your sheets and show the appropriate view according to the model. Like I said before it shouldn’t matter if you are coding for SwiftUI or UIKit if you take all the information both frameworks need to make a similar view you should be able to create a generic model.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, so if I'm understanding this correctly, you want to handle the logic for showing different sheets from the Generic View.
First, let's build the GenericView:

```swift
struct GenericView<Content: View, FirstSheet: View, SecondSheet: View>: View {
    private enum ModalSheet: Identifiable {
        var id: Self { return self }
        
        case firstSheet
        case secondSheet
    }
    
    @State private var showModalSheet: ModalSheet?
    private let content: () -> Content
    private let firstSheet: () -> FirstSheet
    private let secondSheet: () -> SecondSheet
    public init(
        @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content,
        @ViewBuilder firstSheet: @escaping () -> FirstSheet,
        @ViewBuilder secondSheet: @escaping () -> SecondSheet
    ) {
        self.content = content
        self.firstSheet = firstSheet
        self.secondSheet = secondSheet
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            content()
            VStack {
                Button("Show first sheet") {
                    showModalSheet = .firstSheet
                }
                Button("Show second sheet") {
                    showModalSheet = .secondSheet
                }
            }
        }
            .sheet(item: $showModalSheet) { modalSheet in
                switch modalSheet {
                case .firstSheet:
                    firstSheet()
                case .secondSheet:
                    secondSheet()
                }
            }
    }
}
```

**Note that I created an enum inside `GenericView` to handle the logic for the different sheets**

So now, if I want to use the generic view inside a regular view, I would do the following:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GenericView {
            Color.yellow.ignoresSafeArea()
        } firstSheet: {
            Text("Content for First Sheet")
        } secondSheet: {
            Text("Content for Second Sheet")
        }

    }
}
```

This way you can control which sheet you present as well as dismissing them without using a ViewModel.

Is this more or less what you had in mind?

Comment: The op already said that they don’t want an enum